# Open Documents from iBooks in my application

Tags: iphone, ibooks

Is it possible to open a document from iBooks in my application? I found only that:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"itms-books:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

but with this I can only open iBooks from my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible, there is no API to get document from iBooks.